# Trying to delete columns in a df using select() in the dplyr r-package

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I have a dataframe with more than 150 variables. But many variables are not relevant and I am trying to get rid of them.

I use the following:

```
totaalfile <- select(totaalfile, 
                     - c("TIME_ACCURACY", "WIND_DIRECTION", "WIND_FORCE", 
                           "WATER_VISIBILITY", "SALINITY_FACTOR", "SWELL_HEIGHT", 
                           "TIDAL_PHASE", "and many more columns here after"))
```

I get this error:

> ```
> Error in -c("TIME_ACCURACY", "WIND_DIRECTION", "WIND_FORCE", "WATER_VISIBILITY",  : 
>   invalid argument to unary operator
> ```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Error in -c("TIME_ACCURACY", "WIND_DIRECTION", "WIND_FORCE", "WATER_VISIBILITY",  : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Use `select(totaalfile, -TIME_ACCURACY, -WIND_DIRECTION, -WIND_FORCE, ...)`. Please read `?select`, it uses non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Btw, the error comes from using `-` and a character vector, as in `- c("x")`.

Comment: Thanks Axeman! It works for me now.

Comment: `select(totaalfile, -c(TIME_ACCURACY, WIND_DIRECTION, IND_FORCE, ...))` should work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the names you want to remove in a vector, you can remove them using `select_` like so:

```
iris %>%
  select_(.dots = paste0("-", c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length"))) %>%
  head
```

which gives:

```
  Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

`select_` uses standard evaluation, so allows more flexibility in constructing arguments from character vectors, if you need to be able to do that. Here, it pastes the column names you want to remove with "-" to remove them, much like @Axeman's comment suggestion, except this allows you to automate that process from a stored variable, e.g.:

```
colsToDrop <- c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length")

iris %>%
  select_(.dots = paste0("-", colsToDrop)) %>%
  head
```